# How can I speed up my python script?

Tags: mysql, sqlperformance

I have the following python script that reads from a file line by line and executes mysql update queries. It is extremely slow, each query seems to take over 1 second. Any idea why it is so slow?

```
   with open(fname) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip()
            email, name  = line.split(':')[0], line.split(':')[-1]
            try:
                cursor.execute("UPDATE user SET name=%s WHERE email=%s", (name, email))
            except mariadb.Error as error:
                print("Error: {}".format(error))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to fix the performance problem by using an index:

```
create index idx_user_email on user(email);
```

1 second for an update is a long time.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot that solved it. After creating an index for the column the script is running much faster. Thanks alot.

Comment: Apart from index, will batch update make it faster? right now he is firing one update query for each line. Rather if he makes a batch update, will there be performance difference?

Comment: @Ymartin . . . The batch update will not fix the problem (probably) unless the table also has the index.  I would not go for a "batch update".  Instead, I would load the file into a table using `load data infile` and then use a `join` for the update (along with the index).

Comment: @GordonLinoff .Thanks. Helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using more than one thread.

```
import threading

with open(fname) as f:

    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        email, name  = line.split(':')[0], line.split(':')[-1]
        thread = threading.Thread(target=updateUser,  args=[name, email] )
        thread.start()


def updateUser(name, email):
    try:
        cursor.execute("UPDATE user SET name=%s WHERE email=%s", (name, email))
    except mariadb.Error as error:
        print("Error: {}".format(error))
```

It could avoid the wasted time while you are querying the database. So while the query it's being processed by the database, your program will be preparing another query.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to be fanatical, you could also turn journaling off:

```
db= sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("PRAGMA synchronous = OFF")
cursor.execute("PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF")
```